# Does an annotation object extend the Object class in java?

Tags: java

I know that an annotation object is created implicitly by the JVM. Also, I know that all objects in java inherit the superclass Object. However, if by reflection you retrieve an annotation object, it doesn't seem to have the methods ***finalise()*** and ***clone()*** which are defined by the **Object** class in java. Does an annotation object indeed inherit the Object class? Is there a reason why an annotation object doesn't define those methods?

An example code snippet here:

```
Class<autobot> jane = autobot.class;
about frank = jane.getAnnotation(about.class);
frank.clone();      // This generates an error
frank.finalize();  //  This generates an error
```

Where "**autobot**" is an annotated class and "**about**" is the annotation type.

Comment: Try with the `public` methods such as `notifyAll`

Answer (score 8):

It does. `clone()` and `finalize()` aren't public. This doesn't work either:

```
Object o = new Object();
o.clone(); // nope
o.finalize(); // nope
```

It *may* work on certain classes. For example, this DOES work:

```
ArrayList<String> o = new ArrayList<String>();
o.clone();
```

That's simply because `class ArrayList` itself has overridden the `clone()` method and made it `public`. You can override a method and make it more public (you can't make em less public).

The type def of an annotation doesn't make anything more public.